# ValueError in text file after writing through one program and graphing through another

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

So, I have a program that writes on to the txt file

```
 global v,t

    v=random.randint(1,4)
    txt=open('bv.txt','a')
    txt.write(str(v)+","+str(t) +"\n")
    t+=1
    txt.close()
```

after getting two values, I take these values and graph them through another program which i plan to integrate into my main GUI.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph():

            x=[]
            y=[]

            readFile= open('bv.txt', 'r')

            sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')

            readFile.close()

            for plotpair in sepFile:
                xAndY = plotpair.split(',')
                y.append((xAndY[0]))
                x.append(int(xAndY[1]))


            plt.plot(x, y)
            plt.show()

 graph()
```

So after doing this, it seems pretty staright forward, but I get an error stating that value cannot be added. I had initially used random.uniform but since it had a valueError that int cannot convert base 10 values, i eventually tried random.randint which gave int values yet it gave the same error. 
The first time i had added my own valeus in the text file, it worked, yet after deleting those and inserting values through my program it just does not seem to work. 
Please give your inputs for this.

Comment: The `xAndY` list contains strings.  
The `xAndY[1]` string is converted to int while `xAndY[0]` is not.

Comment: Could you print the trace back and show the input sample

Comment: xAndY[0] isnt converted even though I get a pure integral value through the program. Which is quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind using `numpy`, `np.genfromtxt` can do this a lot more simply:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def graph():
    x,y=np.genfromtxt('bv.txt',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

graph()
```

Comment: it says too many values to be input. Even though i have around 6 data inputs.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the `unpack=True` option. I've edited my answer, which should work for you now.

Comment: another option is to use `data=np.genfromtxt('bv.txt',delimiter=',')`, and then `plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])`

Comment: what is the difference if i can ask?

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot! I have been trying to learn these libraries but its pretty tough. Could you give suggestions on any tutorials or learning material? I actually wanted to get a live dynamic graph in my GUI.

Comment: The main difference is personal preference: the option in the answer gives to two arrays of x and y, while the second option loads everything from the file into one big array, which you can the plot by taking slices. one way or the other might be neater for you, depending on the rest of your code structure.